# Vertical Scrollbar to Table

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, scrollbar

I need to add Vertical scrollbar to table ID="items"(depending on height or number of items in table),I tried by adding style="height:200px;Overflow:auto" but due to ng-repeat,Scrollbar is added to individual row rather than complete table.Can anyone help me out?

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px" ng-show="itemCodesExists.length > 0">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="width:100px;text-align:center">ItemCode</th>
        <th style="width:100px;text-align:center">ItemDescription</th>
        <th style="width:100px;text-align:center">ItemQuantity</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemCodesExists">
      <table id="items" style="overflow-y:auto" border="1">
        <tr style="text-align:center">
          <td style="width:100px">{{item.ItemCode}}</td>
          <td style="width:120px">{{item.Description}}</td>
          <td style="width:100px">{{item.Quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think table not have property overflow
you should set it in here

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemCodesExists"
style="overflow-y:auto;height:200px;">
```